# Unable to update redux store on manipulating the initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Using this action for updating the particular componentId in redux initial state. Facing 6the following violation error while updating the initial state.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path "currentActivityJSON.draggedItems.1.isDisable". This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

Code:

```
export function draggedItem(currentActivityJSON, componentId) {
    let draggedItems = currentActivityJSON.draggedItems;
    for (var i=0; i < draggedItems.length; i++ ) {
        if (componentId === draggedItems[i].componentId) {
            draggedItems[i ].isDisable = true;
        }
    }
    return {
        type: DRAGGED_ITEM,
        currentActivityJSON: Object.assign({}, currentActivityJSON, {
            ...currentActivityJSON,
            draggedItems:  draggedItems
        })
    };
}
```

This is initial_state.json and need to update the 2nd array item `isDisable=true.

```
"currentActivityJSON": {
    "defaultItems": [],
    "expectedItems": [
      "GLASS_BOTTLE"
    ],
    "isDoneEnabled": true,
    "draggedItems": [
      {
      "imageUrl": "../src/media/images/activities/box_big@2x.png",
      "componentId": "CARTBOARD_BOX",
      "componentText": "CardBoard Box",
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "70%",
      "isDisable": false
    },
      {
        "imageUrl": "../src/media/images/activities/bottle_big@2x.png",
        "componentId": "PLASTIC_BOTTLE",
        "componentText": "Plastic 2L Bottle",
        "width": "50%",
        "height": "50%",
        "isDisable": false
      },
      {
        "imageUrl": "../src/media/images/activities/glasstank_big1@2x.png",
        "componentId": "GLASS_BOTTLE",
        "componentText": "Glass Tank",
        "width": "80%",
        "height": "70%",
        "isDisable": false
      }]
  }
```

Comment: Can any one help on updating a particular key value in the state. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of the code mutates items in the original `draggedItems` array:

```
let draggedItems = currentActivityJSON.draggedItems;
for (var i=0; i < draggedItems.length; i++ ) {
    if (componentId === draggedItems[i].componentId) {
        draggedItems[i ].isDisable = true;
    }
}
```

Instead create a new `draggedItems` array, replace the changed item:

```
const draggedItems = currentActivityJSON.draggedItems.map((item) => {
    if(componentId === draggedItems[i].componentId) {
        return {
            ...item,
            isDisable: true
        };
    }

    return item;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid mutations outside of the reducer by instantly returning the action in the action creator. Instead of for-loops, use ES6 spread and array methods.

`export function draggedItem(currentActivityJSON, componentId) {
    return {
        type: DRAGGED_ITEM,
        currentActivityJSON: {
            ...currentActivityJSON,
            draggedItems: [
              ...currentActivityJSON.draggedItems.filter(item => item.componentId !== componentId), {
                ...currentActivityJSON.draggedItems.find(item => item.componentId === componentId),
                isDisable: true
              }
           ]
        })
    };
}`

By the way, I wouldn't name it "JSON" becaus in JavaScript, it is just an object (literal). And if you are using the [object spread operator](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) (`...object`), you don't really need to call Object.assign().

But I'm wondering, if it wouldn't be better to just dispatch the  componentId in the action and perform the change of currentActivityJSON in the reducer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But here manipulate the isdisable property by using the componentid . Is there any better approach for it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. A better approach for what exactly? More context would be helpful. Is componentId the ID of a react component? There are probably more fundamental flaws going on here... Why is the initial state so similar to the action creator's first argument?

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Here  componentId is a react Component Id. Yes I am just updating the particular key in initial state after dispatching the action. Is there any flaw for just updating the particular key of initial state?

Answer (score 0):

This code works like a charm!

```
 const draggedItems = currentActivityJSON.draggedItems.map((item) => {
        if(componentId === draggedItems[i].componentId) {
            return {
                ...item,
                isDisable: true
            };
        }

        return item;
    });
```